# Enforce logon time policy on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there any way to enforce when FBA users can login or not to a SharePoint site?

Comment: Do you mean for example: users cannot log in between 8pm & 4am? Give us an example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I need. Users can only logon from mon to friday, each day from 6am to 7pm. I'm thinking about having a custom login page or using sharepoint events but I didnt have much time to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the timeframe a user can log in, you have a few options. The easiest approach would be to implement FBA, build your own login page that essentially blocks the users during the hours you wish.

This link will get you close to where you need to be, although it covers much more than you need. You'll tap into the signInControl_LoggingIn method and set e.Cancel = true during blackout hours.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/08/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-fba-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx